# What type of Visual Studio c# project should i select for making an instant messenger application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, instant-messaging

what c# project must i choose in order to create an instant messaging application in visual studio.
pls help.

Thanks. :)

Comment: I'd expect a few different project types. But before you decide, you really need to come up with some high level architecture to drive the decision.

Comment: I agree - winforms, wpf...........................

Comment: depends , is this a local networking im client, is it a web Im client, is an authentication service few more details would be appreciated

Comment: A console app is doable....

Comment: the application is for web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to plan a lot of different things during application design process. The main project anyway, of course, should be a windows form application or a WPF... then, eventually some libraries.

Answer (score 0):

This question is far too common and will be closed soon.

But to give you some suggestions for directions you can go next:

- Design you overall architecture first
- Are there technical restrictions for the UI?
- You have basically following options: Console App, WPF, WinForms, Silverlight, ASP
- Since you said in a comment that the app should be a web app, maybe you want create an ASP.Net application.